# Distributed Hash Table DHT minimum relays needed

Tags: onion-services

(BLUF) How many relays are needed to create a workable TOR Distributed Hash Table?

My original question was "what would cause the TB to log a valid HS name to be "invalid" and "rejected". After reading about the steps involved with connecting to an HS; I realized I probably do not have a sufficient number of stable relays to create the DHT. So the HS name could not be looked up in the DHT. I have an isolated research TOR with 3 DAs and 40 relays, a few of each type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have enough amount of nodes, so you better start them *all* in debugging and verbose mode - asmy experiments showed, you need 3 DAs and at least 16 guards and 16 regular nodes